# Hyperlinks sub folders file

Tags: excel, vba

Hello everyone yesterday ı try to do [Save Excel Row Via Vba Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71478920/save-excel-row-via-vba-loop), now my problem is give hyplinks that file via macro.
I try to explain in photo and my codes are below

[image]

```
Sub Hyperlinks()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim hl As Hyperlink
Const RootPath As String = "X:\EVEREST-2\EVEREST ERP\ÜRETİM\PDM SOLID DOSYA YOLU\"
Const SeriCol As Long = 3
Const NameCol As Long = 4
Const YearCol As Long = 24

Set wks = ActiveSheet

Dim r As Long: r = FirstRow
Dim FileBaseName As String: FileBaseName = ws.Cells(r, SeriCol)
Dim hl_name As String: hl_name = ws.Cells(r, NameCol)
Dim year As String: year = ws.Cells(r, YearCol)

Do Until Len(hl_name) = 0
    wks.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(r, NameCol), Address:=(RootPath & year & "\" & FileBaseName & ".bat"TextToDisplay:=hl_name)
    r = r + 1
Loop


MsgBox "Hyperlinks created.", vbInformation End sub
```

Comment: What is your question? I'm guessing that you also need to put those statements assigning `FileBaseName`, `hl_name` and `year` values into the `Do Until` loop after `r = r + 1` so that its value will be updated with each increment of `r`.

Comment: Yes ı try to do what u type

Comment: And I assume there's a problem still? You need to update your question and explain in details what's not working with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Hyperlinks

- ' *** You want to reference the model cell before and at the end of the loop.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateHyperlinks()
    
    Const RootPath As String = "X:\EVEREST-2\EVEREST ERP\ÜRETIM\PDM SOLID DOSYA YOLU\"
    Const YearCol As String = "X"
    Const SerialCol As String = "C"
    Const ModelCol As String = "D"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim r As Long: r = FirstRow
    Dim ModelCell As Range: Set ModelCell = wks.Cells(r, ModelCol) ' ***
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim YearPath As String
    Dim Serial As String
    
    Do Until Len(CStr(ModelCell.Value)) = 0
        
        YearPath = CStr(wks.Cells(r, YearCol)) & "\"
        Serial = CStr(wks.Cells(r, SerialCol))
        FilePath = RootPath & YearPath & Serial & ".bat"
        
        wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ModelCell, Address:=FilePath
        
        r = r + 1
        Set ModelCell = wks.Cells(r, ModelCol) ' ***
    
    Loop

    MsgBox "Hyperlinks created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma missing between `".bat"` and `TextToDisplay`:

> ```
>  Address:=(RootPath & year & "\" & FileBaseName & ".bat"TextToDisplay:=hl_name)
> ```

Note:  There is no need to use the `TextToDisplay` parameter when the display text is the same as the anchor cell value.

### Refactored Code

```
Sub Hyperlinks()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    Const RootPath As String = "X:\EVEREST-2\EVEREST ERP\ÜRETIM\PDM SOLID DOSYA YOLU\"
    Const SeriCol As Long = 3
    Const NameCol As Long = 4
    Const YearCol As Long = 24

    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim r As Long: r = FirstRow
    Dim FileBaseName As String: FileBaseName = ws.Cells(r, SeriCol)
    
    Dim year As String: year = ws.Cells(r, YearCol)
    Dim Address As String
    
    Do Until Len(hl_name) = 0
        Address = RootPath & year & "\" & FileBaseName & ".bat"
        wks.Hyperlinks.Add ws.Cells(r, NameCol), Address:=Address
        r = r + 1
    Loop


    MsgBox "Hyperlinks Added"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ı fix it now it works

```
Sub Hyperlinks1()
Dim hl As Hyperlink
Const RootPath As String = "X:\EVEREST-2\EVEREST ERP\ÜRETİM\PDM SOLID DOSYA YOLU\"
Const SeriCol As Long = 3
Const NameCol As Long = 4
Const YearCol As Long = 24



Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim r As Long: r = 4
Dim FileBaseName As String: FileBaseName = ws.Cells(r, SeriCol)
Dim hl_name As String: hl_name = ws.Cells(r, NameCol)
Dim year As String: year = ws.Cells(r, YearCol)
year = Right(year, 4)

Do Until Len(hl_name) = 0
With ws
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(r, NameCol), _
 Address:=RootPath & year & "\" & FileBaseName & ".bat", _
 ScreenTip:="Click to open 3D Solid File", _
 TextToDisplay:=hl_name
End With
r = r + 1
FileBaseName = ws.Cells(r, SeriCol)
hl_name = ws.Cells(r, NameCol)
year = ws.Cells(r, YearCol)
year = Right(year, 4)
Loop



MsgBox "Hyperlinks created.", vbInformation
End Sub
```